# How do I start/stop/restart a windows service on a remote machine using .net

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services

Currently I am developing desktop application that start/stop/restart windows services.

```
    public static void StartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
    {
        ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
        try
        {
            TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

            service.Start();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
        }
        catch
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Now I want code to perform same action on remote system(other system on the same network).

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder why you got a -1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to instantiate the ServiceController with the overloaded constructor that accepts a machine name, like this:

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName, machineName);
```

Comment: Hi Rewinder,
Thanks a lot for the answer. When I access the service of other server with is code I am getting this error. 

"Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'PVUKRTSINJ02'. This operation might require other privileges."

PVUKRTSINJ02 is the server I am trying to connect. It is in other domain. But I can connect to this server from my domain through remote desktop connection with my credentials.

Comment: @Nani: I don't think that is the actual excpetion. Try to catch the exception in your catch block, and see if you can get some more useful info.

Comment: @Nani ServiceController uses different protocols. Make sure you are not blocking the File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks service and created a connection to the target computer using the domain credential via File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks first.

Comment: How do I pass credentials here along with MachiName ?